# Cells' colors change only after exiting the app

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors

I am trying to have some cells in a table view in different colors. The problem is that they become colored only after exiting the app. Every time I create a new cell it will be colored by the default color (but after exiting the app or simulator and reopening it, they are all colored as I want).

What should I do in order to refresh the color the moment after the cell is added? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(indexPath.row==0) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:36.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
if(indexPath.row==1) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:72.0/255.0 green:214.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
if(indexPath.row==2) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:132.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
if(indexPath.row==3) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:84.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
if(indexPath.row==4) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:207.0/255.0 blue:7.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
if(indexPath.row==5) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:157.0/255.0 blue:7.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

This is my final code:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
} }
```

Comment: Why are people down voting the OP's own answer to their own question?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something you should be doing in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which returns a cell for the given index path. As part of the setup for your cell, you can set it's background color.

Comment: I agree. This should be done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I was just testing it and although in my case it was working just fine, the refresh rate was dropping considerably implying that the method causes a lot of performance issues if it needs to redraw each cell after it's already cached.

Comment: @Arash look at this OP solution…… you'll be speechless

Comment: Actually, using `willDisplayCell` is the proper place for setting the background color of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Working code.

**1) Set cell identifier**

[image]

**2) In your .m file…**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==0) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:36.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    if(indexPath.row==1) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:72.0/255.0 green:214.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    if(indexPath.row==2) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:132.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    if(indexPath.row==3) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:84.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    if(indexPath.row==4) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:207.0/255.0 blue:7.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    if(indexPath.row==5) cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:157.0/255.0 blue:7.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Just before you posted I have solved the problem ( my solution is in the answers section) . However, I tried your solution, too but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Wow. you made a working code not work. What a pro! (clap)(clap)